# Why mirror modifier does not merge?

Tags: mirror

Goodmorning, I am working to imitate the tutorial at this link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbSmoZCrP8I

At minute 5:15-5:30 he creates a circle with 8 vertices, deletes 3/4 of the figure and then use the mirror modifier to complete the operation.

I'm trying to imitate him, but after deleting the 3/4 of the circle I apply the mirror modifier but the circle does not close.
My result is:

[image]

Instead in the original tutorial the circle is:

[image]

I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: Note that he rotates the circle in **edit mode**. You have rotated your circle in object mode as you can from the transform values in the top right of the 3d view. You will have to apply the rotation now (Ctrl A).

Comment: Thank you, now it works!

Answer (score 1):

First he added a circle consisting of eight vertices that was rotated by 22.5° on z-axis in object mode. The quarter circle was made by inserting a vertex on each side to align with the axis and then deleting the rest. You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then point and click at the space between the circle vertices with your mouse to create one vertex in the middle.

[image]

Comment: It's the same operation I've just done, I followed his path but I don't understand why the result is different.